# Using a custom finder in a custom route class

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

This custom route class works, but when I replace the query with the custom finder it returns the error: Unknown finder method "published". Is it not possible to use a custom finder here?

```
class ContentsRoute extends Route {

public function parse($url) {

    $params = parent::parse($url);
    if (!($params)) {
        return false;
    }

    $pages = Cache::read('pages');
    if ($pages === false) {
        $contents = TableRegistry::get('Contents');
        // custom finder 
        // $query = $contents->find('published');

        $query = $contents->find()
            ->select(['id', 'path', 'public'])
            ->where(['Contents.published' => 1]);

        $pages = $query->toArray();


        Cache::write('pages', $pages);
    }

    if (isset($pages[$url])) {
        $params['pass'] = array('path' => $url);
        return $params;
    }

    return false;

    }

}

//ContentsTable.php
public function findPublished(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query = $this->find()
        ->select(['id', 'path', 'public'])
        ->where(['Contents.published' => 1]);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: `debug(get_class($contents))` - You probably do not have an instance of your table class.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

I needed to add the className to the options array for TableRegistry::get('Contents')